# Symfony mod_rewrite how to corretly loading css/js files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

When I started use mod_rewrite, page not loading css/js/img files. This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
        RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
        RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

        RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|img)/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/$(.*) localhost/web/img/$2 [L,R=301]
        RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /web/app.php [QSA,L]
       #RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My project is located in /var/www/project files,  I copied css/js/img folders from **/var/www/web** into **var/www/css** etc. but it didn't help. The files are loading when I change path to css file to `<link href="/web/css/4279b2a.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`before was `href="/css/4279b2a.css"`

If I add to src "web" than wokrs

```
<img src="web/img/weather_icons/Blizzard.gif" alt="Symfony!">
```

How correctly to add css/js/img files

Comment: Why you don't set the DocumentRoot to the web directory?

Comment: What. are. you. trying. to. achieve?

Comment: @cheesemacfly correctly loading css/js/img files